# maven plugins stored where

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

Where are maven plugins stored? in the local repository as well? what happens if you build your application with eclipse? does it store the plugins inside the eclipse/plugins folder or still in the local repository?

Comment: +1 for the google search term subject of this question. We soon will all revert to googlespeak.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> Where are maven plugins stored? in the local repository as well?

Yes. Plugins are downloaded from a remote repository and stored in the local repository. The exact final location will thus depend on the groupId of the plugins (the core plugins end up  in `~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins` where `~/` stands for your home directory for example in windows server 2016 it is stored under this path `C:\Users\YourUserName\.m2`)

> what happens if you build your application with eclipse?

Hmm... Nothing special.

> Does it store the plugins inside the eclipse/plugins folder or still in the local repository?

No, Maven (embedded or external) uses the location defined in the `<localRepository>` element of the global or user [**settings**](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html) (which defaults to `~/.m2/repository`), unless you overrode the **Local Repository** path in **Window > Preferences > Maven > User Settings**.